# Netbeans: Unable to integrate Tomcat (Ubuntu)

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans, server

I use Netbeans as my IDE and unfortunately, I am unable to integrate Tomcat as a server instance. I am getting the error: "The Specified Server Location (Catalina Home) folder is not valid". However, it appears to be incorrect.

My installation folder for Apache Tomcat is in my /usr/local/apache-tomcat9 directory. I have the environmental variable of CATALINA_HOME currently pointing to that directory.

I think I have given a good enough written description of the conundrum that I am facing, but here is also additional picture proof. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, CATALINA_HOME is /usr/share/tomcat_VERSION, and CATALINA_BASE is /var/lib/tomcat_VERSION.Try that location instead of what you have used.

Comment: Hello, I tried that (I installed tomcat now via apt-get so that it would default to the normal location) and now I am getting the error message: "the <CATALINA_HOME>/conf/server.xml can not be read"

Comment: You have to change the read permission for the server.xml file. using chmod linux commands